# Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'client_fk_name' in the referenced table 'client'

Tags: mysql

Why am I unable to add these foreign keys?

I'm trying to make clientName and employeeId both foreign keys in the events table. I realize I may not need clientEmail, but my error is currently showing at clientName.

```
CREATE TABLE client
(
  clientName    VARCHAR(50)    PRIMARY KEY   NOT NULL,
  clientID      INT            NOT NULL      auto_increment,
  clientEmail   VARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,
  clientPass    VARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,
  phone         VARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE admin
(
  Name         VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL,
  adminId      INT           NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY   auto_increment,
  adminPass    VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL,
  adminEmail   VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
  Name            VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL,
  employeeId      INT           NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY  auto_increment,
  employeePass    VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL,
  employeeEmail   VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE event
(
  eventId       INT           PRIMARY KEY   auto_increment,
  employeeId    INT           NOT NULL,
  clientName    VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL,
  clientEmail   VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL,
  Constraint client_fk_name
  Foreign Key (clientName)
  references client (clientName),
  Constraint client_fk_email
  Foreign Key (clientEmail)
  references client (clientEmail),
  Constraint employee_fk_id
  Foreign Key (employeeId)
  references employee (employeeId)
);
```

Only these four tables.

Comment: A foreign key is intended to link two tables together  with the primary key, not data such as name or email.

Comment: And this error: ` there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key` . Maybe you need `clientID INT NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY  ` ?

Comment: @abrush Take a look at the changes made: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/171. Keep in mind when creating foreign key the columns must be indexed in the table you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

So, one way to deal with this is to call the attribute in the parent table UNIQUE. This solves this error. However, as a side effect in my current experience, *upon inserting* into the database you may experience problems if your values are not unique (possibly obviously). But if you can guarantee *uniqueness* then just add *Unique* and you will be fine.

*Unique* specifies an attribute as a *candidate key*. Essentially it’s saying this could have been the primary key, but we chose something else.